# Access DataTable row

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a `DataTable` and I access its rows using a `foreach` loop

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
   userId = Convert.ToInt32(row[BundleSchema.ParamUpdatedBy]);
}
```

but knowing that my `DataTable` contains only a single `row`, how can I access it without `looping` through it?

Comment: The [`DataRowCollection `](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) has also an [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.item(v=vs.110).aspx) like the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Index on `Rows`

```
DataRow row = table.Rows[0];
userId = Convert.ToInt32(row[BundleSchema.ParamUpdatedBy]);
```